# How to change the text of the button using document.getElementById("myButton").text="myText";

Tags: javascript

I want my button to change the text(for eg: "save" to "edit" ) on a linkbutton click.

```
document.getElementById("btnAddAction").text="edit";
```

but this syntax is not working can you help me ?

Comment: `.innerText = "edit"`

Comment: use innerText or textContent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `textContent` not text

```js
document.getElementById("btnAddAction").textContent="edit";
```

```html
<button id="btnAddAction">text</button>
```

Using `innerText`

```js
document.getElementById("btnAddAction").innerText="edit";
```

```html
<button id="btnAddAction">text</button>
```

Using `innerHTML`

```js
document.getElementById("btnAddAction").innerHTML="edit";
```

```html
<button id="btnAddAction">text</button>
```

Comment: As i was using the master page the ID that formed was concatinated with the contentplaceholder and hence it could not find the element now i am able to and your solution works for me thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

`text` is not the DOM node property. You can try either use [`Node.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) or [`HTMLElement.innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText)

Answer (score 1):

1. `<button id="thebutton">
     <span class="ui-button-text">My Text</span>
   </button>`
   Then use `$("#thebutton span").text("My NEW Text");`
2. `<button id="thebutton"> My Text</span> </button>`

   Then use `$("#thebutton").text("My NEW Text");`

Comment: i want to change by using dom

Answer (score 1):

```
    <asp:Linkbutton id="BtnLink" runat="server" Text="Save" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:Linkbutton>


  $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).click(function () {
            $("#BtnLink").text("Edit");
            return false;
        });
    });
```

please try this code